# Is there a model.summary() in Trax?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, trax

I'm working with [Trax](https://trax-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), a framework built by the Google Brain team to work with deep learning models as an alternative to [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/). As a TensorFlow developer, I'm pretty used to the `model.summary()` method (documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/models_and_layers#model_summary)) to display a full model summary, for example:

```py
model.summary()


Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 16, 303)]         0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 16, 256)           442368    
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, 16, 22)            5654      
=================================================================
Total params: 448,022
Trainable params: 448,022
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Is there  something equivalent in Trax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there does not appear to be a method similar to `.summary()` in Trax; the closest thing is that you can print the model. Adapting the [example from the documentation](https://trax-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/trax_intro.html#Models):

```
from trax import layers as tl

model = tl.Serial(
    tl.Embedding(vocab_size=8192, d_feature=256),
    tl.Mean(axis=1),  # Average on axis 1 (length of sentence).
    tl.Dense(2),      # Classify 2 classes.
)

print(model)
```

Result:

```
Serial[
  Embedding_8192_256
  Mean
  Dense_2
]
```

Although nowhere as detailed as Tensorflow's `model.summary()`, there is still useful info in the print output: notice that the parameters of the embedding layer are included in the printout; notice also that, if you change the model's last layer to `tl.Dense(3)`, the respective output will change to `Dense_3`.